# sum in a dynamic sheet where multiple conditions are met and divide

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

My form reactions are coming in, I have translated this in another 
second sheet.
That sheet pulls data that matches the form questions.

The data that matches have a value for example 306 what I'm trying to achieve is that the respondents that match the criteria get a part of the 306 if only 1 match is there then they get 306 but if 2 match I want to divide to these 2 respondents but with the conditions it's divided % in a way above the sheet.

I don't know even where to start because it's so dynamical I get stuff half done so I'm not thinking in the right direction.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B8, A10:C13, 3, 0)))
```

---

```
=IFERROR(B10/COUNTIF(B$2:B$8, A10))
```

[image: 0]